# logstash || Insert Apache log file to Oracle Database

Tags: logstash

I am trying to insert my daily Apache logs to Oracle database. I did the following configuration file coding, however i am getting error - Couldn't find any output plugin. I have done testing on 6.3.2 & 5.6.0 versions of logstash. In short my input will be a text file and output will be my database(in this case Oracle). Can someone please help with the code. I did research but i couldn't find any correct answer.

```html
input
{
file
{
path => "C:\Users\ssn\logstash\Input\access.log"
start_position => "beginning"
}
}
output
{

jdbc{
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:xyz/Helloxyz1@xyz1000:PORT:1521"
statement => [ "INSERT INTO LOGS (IP_ADDRESS, USER_IDENTIFIER, USERID, REQUEST_TIME, CLIENT_REQUEST, RESPONSE_CODE, SIZEOFOBJECT, COOKIES) 
VALUES(?, ? , ?, ?, ? , ?, ?, ?)", "IP_ADDRESS", "USER_IDENTIFIER", "USERID", "REQUEST_TIME", "CLIENT_REQUEST", "RESPONSE_CODE", "SIZEOFOBJECT", "COOKIES"]
}

}
```